# Is SBJsonParser's error, "Valid fragment, but not JSON", correct?

Tags: objective-c, json

According to http://www.jsonlint.com/ 1234 is valid JSON but when I do `[@"1234" JSONValue]` I get the Valid fragment but not JSON error.  Am I missing something here or is SBJsonParser just wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SBJsonParser` requires that the root structure in the JSON be an array or an object; in your example, you have a number. Either of the following will work:

```
NSArray *array = [@"[1234]" JSONValue];
NSDictionary *dictionary = [@"{\"number\": 1234}" JSONValue];
```

Comment: The library is correct; it complies with RFC 4627 which states: "A JSON text is a serialized object or array." (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4627)